# Envio de e-mail usando phpMailer

Tags: php, aplicação-web, email, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail com várias variáveis passadas via post. Não consigo enviar o conteúdo do e-mail com todas as variáveis. Qual seria a sintaxe correta? Segue abaixo o código:

```
$name = $_POST['nome'];
$zip = $_POST['cep'];
$adress = $_POST ['endereco'];
$number = $_POST['numero'];
$comp = $_POST['complemento'];
$neigh = $_POST['bairro'];
$city = $_POST['cidade'];
$state = $_POST['estado'];
$iemail = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['telefone'];
$product = $_POST['produto'];
$model = $_POST['modelo'];
$brand = $_POST['marca'];
$report = $_POST['laudo'];
$date = $_POST['data'];

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.meudominio.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'contato@meudominio.com';// SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'minhasenha';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('contato@meudominio.com', 'Contato');
$mail->addAddress($iemail);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('contato@meudominio.com', 'Contato');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Sua Ordem de Serviço Grupo SAB';
$mail->Body    = '
    <table id="recibo">
        <h1>Ordem de serviço</h1>
        <p>Cliente:'.$name'</p>
        <p>CEP:'.$zip'</p>
        <p>Endereço:'.$adress'</p>
        <p>Numero:'.$number'</p>
        <p>Complemento:'.$comp'</p>
        <p>Bairro:'.$neigh'</p>
        <p>Cidade:'.$city'</p>
        <p>Estado:'.$state'</p>
        <p>Produto:'.$produtc'</p>
        <p>Modelo:'.$model'</p>
        <p>Marca:'.$brand'</p>
        <p>Laudo:'.$report'</p>
    </table>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

?>

Comment: Quando você diz que nao consegue enviar com TODAS variáveis, significa que algumas funcionam?

Comment: Não. Todas as variáveis funcionam corretamente. Porem, no momento de construir o corpo do email, em <prev>$mail->Body = ''<code>eu estou tentando incluir todas as variáveis fechando a aspas simples, concatenando a variável e abrindo a aspa simples e sigo nesse procedimento até o fim do body. Mas ai não consigo enviar o email e resulta em erro

Comment: Ta aos contrario. Use Aspas para abrir a string e aspas simples para as tags. Mais qual erro vc recebe?

Comment: Você está concatenando de forma errada.

Comment: Esse erro: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/storage/9/d0/82/brastempconsuleletr1/public_html/admin/enviarods.php on line 83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seu problema seja a falta do operador `.` para efetuar a concatenação dos valores das variáveis com o restante da *string*. Perceba, por exemplo, que na linha de código

```
<p>Cliente:'.$name'</p>
```

existe apenas o operador de concatenação antes da variável, mas não após, o que gera um erro de sintaxe, pois o interpretador PHP jungará a parte `'</p>` como sendo parte do nome da *string*, gerando o erro. Para corrigir, basta inserir o operador de concatenação novamente após a varável:

```
<p>Cliente:'.$name.'</p>
```

Ou ainda, se preferir uma escrita mais organizada, por fazer o uso da função [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php) para a formatação de *string*.

Além do mais, seria uma boa prática para você adotar em perguntas futuras colocar já no escopo da pergunta a mensagem de erro que você está obtendo na sua aplicação. Isso facilitará muito a vida de quem for te ajudar. Talvez queira ler [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1).

Comment: Ao fazer a correção, colocando o segundo ponto, gerou o seguinte erro:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/storage/9/d0/82/brastempconsuleletr1/public_html/admin/enviarods.php on line 105

Comment: E qual é a linha 105?

Comment: É o final do código, a tag de fechamento ?>, logo após o if de confirmação de envio do email

Comment: Existe a chave de fechamento "}" do último If do código, antes da tag de fechamento?

Comment: Ah, não havia a chave mesmo, agora funcionou. Muito obrigado Anderson!